# In current "DevExpress Chart Demo"... "Large Datasource" is missing "range" bar

Tags: winforms, charts, devexpress

In a video of the DevExpress Chart Demo (see attached image and link below) out on YouTube... the "Large DataSource" demo seems to have some sort of "range" bar at the top where you can see an overview of the data and adjust the left and right of the range and drag the range left and right as well. In the current version of DevExpress the demo doesn't have this feature. Does anyone know how to implement it... or at least what it is officially called so I can look it up in the documentation.

Also, if anybody knows, is there is source code for this demo?

The actual video I'm talking about is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HmA6vANrKKk

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> some sort of "range" bar at the top

Your screenshot is demonstrates the [RangeControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11739), which provides a data range selection functionality.
ChartControl on your screenshot is bound to the RangeControl via the [RangeControl.Client](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRangeControl_Clienttopic) property.

Comment: Awesome... so easy too. - Thanks!